# Button For Adding New data validation (Add new my default workbook in macro excel)

Tags: vba, excel, validation, button

I want to make data validation entry with VBA excel that contain a lot of rules of validation.

I want to make “add new validation entry button”. If I click the button, it will automatically make a new workbook.

This is what i try last night: For the first time, I perepare 2 file of xlsm in my D:\ folder (the files have the same contain).

One file for making validation entry for the first time which contain  “add new validation entry button”. The other one is xlsm file before input the data validation which contain  “add new validation entry button” too (name of the file is (original workbook).   If i click it, it will automatically copy the “original workbook”, close the current program, and give me a new validation entry.

here is my code, but didn't work

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xWbpaste As Workbook
Dim xWbopen As Workbook
Dim wCur As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
filename = NewEntryWorkbook.Text
Set wbCur = ActiveWorkbook

Set xWbcopy = Workbooks.Copy("D:\my macro excel\original workbook")
Set xWbpaste = Workbooks.Paste("D:\my macro excel\" & filename & ".xlsm")
wbCur.close
Set xWbopen = Workbooks.Open("D:\my macro excel\" & filename & ".xlsm")
End Sub
```

Comment: "...it didn't work" - what/how didn't it work? Did you get an error, does it run but not do what you expect, etc.

Comment: I know that there is no methods of workbooks.copy and workbooks.paste. But,I dont know the solution, Sir @bruceWayne. Please help me

Comment: Please add Expected results, Actual results. Concise details please.

Comment: expected result: when i has finished validating for the first time, it will  add new workbook, so I can validation entry for the second time... Actual result: method or data member not found. I dont know how to adding new workbook automatically @chrips

Comment: could you help me sir? @brucewayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a documentation for different programming languages. Also for VBA, but use the examples with care. They are not always using the best syntax. But they are good for getting an overview of the methods and how to use them.

To make a copy of a `WB` see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-savecopyas-method-excel). If you just want to create a new `WB` see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbooks-add-method-excel).

If you add a new `WB` remember that you will get back a `WB`-Object. With [`SaveAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel) you can determine the path and name.

Comment: could I copy a non-activeWB in spesific path with a button in VBA? and Could I open the non-activeWB that I have copied with a button in VBA? that's my problem, sir @UGP

Comment: Ofc. There are mutiple ways to do it. By using [`FileCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2s1c774y(v=vs.90).aspx) (Note: VB example with same function in VBA) or by opening it and then use `SaveAs`. To open a `WB` use [`Workbook.Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel)

Comment: thank you, sir. it works. i use your second option. opening it and SaveAs it. But, there's a little problem. when i've done for validating several documents, they cannot close automatically. could i close all the documents  hat i've validated, except my current workbook? @UGP

Comment: When you use `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(...)` then when you're done `wb.Close`.

Comment: it doesn't work sir @UGP. Set xWbopen = Workbooks.Open("D:\my macro excel\original workbook.xlsm")
xWbopen.Close

Comment: `it doesn't work` is no error description. Please give more details. Close it when you dont need it anymore.

Comment: it doesn't work means the methods "xWbopen.close" prevent me to make new workbook at the same time, the new workbook did not appear. i want something just like this sir, when i've finished validating for first file, it will automatically close the first file and automatically make the second workbook at the same time  @UGP

Comment: I dont really get your point. `wb.Close` will CLOSE your workbook, so use it when you DONT need it anymore.

Comment: i'm sorry sir, i just get for a moment ago. @UGP This is for what i mean:                                                                                           Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim WB As Workbook

For Each WB In Workbooks
     If Not (WB Is ActiveWorkbook) Then WB.Close
Next

End Sub

Comment: Close the `Workbooks` in the same sub you opened them after you're done with them.